# passing Json Post to the controller returns undefined asp.net core

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to save text dynamically with Ajax, but the value that is past to the controller is always null.

Here is my code.

Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcAndAjax.Models.TodoModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<h2>Things that I need to do!</h2>

<div>
    <span>Text:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text, new {@class ="form-control"})<br/>
    <p><a class="btn" onclick="SaveUser()">Save</a></p><br />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <h2>Task's list</h2>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<style>
    #myTable tr th{
        color: white;
        width: 300px;
        height: 40px;
        text-decoration: solid;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function SaveUser() {
        var newText = $("#Text").val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/AddText",
            data: JSON.stringify({getText: newText}),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" +
                    result.Text + "</td></tr>");
                console.log(result.Text);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

and the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddText([FromBody]string getText)
    {
        var newText = new TodoModel();

        newText.Text = getText;
        return Json(newText);
    }
```

But I always get undefined. When I debug it shows me that getText is null. When I log the newText variable from the Jason is shows me the correct value but is still passing null to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your request as an object here

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/AddText",
        data: JSON.stringify({getText: newText}), // <-- makes an object
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" +
                result.Text + "</td></tr>");
            console.log(result.Text);
        }
    })
```

Create a proper object and pass that to your controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddText([FromBody]MyTodoText text)
    {
        var newText = new TodoModel();

        newText.Text = text.getText;
        return Json(newText);
    }
```

Comment: A `string` is an `object` :)

Comment: Basically no, it is a struct. Unless you use string with a captial S, then it is an object.

Comment: Wrong ([string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) is a reference type and is an alias for `String`). And OP is sending the `{ getText: 'someTextValue' }` which cannot be bound to a `MyTodoText` model

Comment: How do you know the mondelbinder cannot bind it? Have you seen the object MyTodoText that doesn't exist yet? It will work, don't worry.

Comment: Because the ModelBinder (or any c# code) cannot do `MyTodoText getText = "someTextValue";` (but I see you just edited it to change the name of the parameter)

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my side. Is fixed now anyway.